# SQL query group by Date shuffle

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like

```
select id, item, date producer from table
```

The result is like this:

```
id         item            producer            date
1          apple            A                  2013-10-26
2          pear             A                  2013-10-26
3          peach            A                  2013-10-26
4          orange           B                  2013-10-26
5          strawberry       B                  2013-10-27
6          melon            B                  2013-10-27
7          apple2           A                  2013-10-27
8          orange3          A                  2013-10-27
```

I need to shuffle these data **"order by DATE DESC"** and get something like this:

```
item            producer
orange3          A
melon            B
apple2           A
strawberry       B
pear             A
orange           B
apple            A
peach            A
melon            B
```

I DON'T want to display like this:

ALL A ITEM... 
ALL B ITEM... Or shuffle something added today with something added yesterday... In my example I don't want to display "orange" before "orange3"

**My solution (but very slow)**

```
Select * from table where date = $date order by rand;
Select * from table where date = $date -1 order by rand;
select * from table where date = $date -2 order by rand;
```

(This is just a concept, $date cannot be decremented with this method)

Comment: To clarify: you need randomly ordered results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following does the trick for you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY `date` DESC, RAND()
```

I just tried it and it seems to do what I think you want.

### Edit

If you want to persist the "shuffle" then add a column of type DOUBLE named `rnd`, do

```
UPDATE `table` SET rnd = RAND()
```

and then in your SELECT statement use

```
.... ORDER BY `date` DESC, `rnd`
```

Comment: it works well! But there is another problem now, each refresh the results are different (this is normal because it is a Rand). It is not very serious for a site. Right now I don't have an idea what can i do... except edit insert rules